# How to create a search box in tkinter that shows data from sqlite3?

Tags: python, sqlite, tkinter

I'm trying to create a search box that accepts the value's ID in the database but I'm having many problems with my code and I don't know how to fix it. This is meant to be a module for my main.py file but this is where I'm pretty much having problems with.

Additional context,
This is a different window where you can edit a specific value of a contact but with a search box.

I have a button that searches and gets the input from the entry box but the user input isn't being read
and I keep getting the error message box stated in the if condition statement that says "Please fill out the entry fields" and sometimes whenever I terminate my program, I then get the second error message box stated in the elif condition statement that says "No such contact found".
The else block doesn't get executed and keeps getting ignored, I'm pretty sure my database has data in it so I'm sure I went wrong with my code.

Where did I go wrong and how do I fix this?

```py
from tkinter import *
import sqlite3
from tkinter import messagebox


def editcontacts():
    window2 = Toplevel()

    # id search box, search btn, and search btn function
    search_box = Entry(window2, font=('@Yu Gothic Light', 18), relief=SOLID, borderwidth=3)
    search_box.place(x=21, y=90,
                   width=300, height=30)

    textvar = StringVar()

    def getdata():
        global get_input
        get_input = search_box.get()

        con = sqlite3.connect('contacts.db')
        c = con.cursor()
        data = c.fetchall()

        if '' in get_input:
            messagebox.showerror('Error', 'Please fill out the entry fields')

        elif len(data) == 0:
            messagebox.showerror('Error', 'No such contact found')

        else:
            c.execute("SELECT * FROM contacts WHERE rowid = :search_box", get_input)
            searched_contact = Label(window2, textvariable=textvar, fg='#ffffff')
            searched_contact.place(x=50, y=150)

            for records in data:
                textvar.set(records[0])

    searchbtn = Button(window2, text='Search contact', command=getdata)
    searchbtn.place(x=50, y=180)

    window2.mainloop()
```

Comment: Why do you call `data = c.fetchall()` just after creating the cursor `c` and haven't executed any `SELECT` statement?

Comment: Thank you so much @acw1668, you gave me a hint on how to fix my program and I finally fixed it after 5 days. Apparently that is one of the problems but the other problem was that I used the wrong operator for my first if condition statement. Instead of `in`, it should be `!=` or `==`

Comment: `'' in get_input` will be always true.  It should be `get_input == ''` instead.

Comment: @acw1668, exactly what I said, but thanks!